# Implicit conversion fails when changing struct to sealed class

Tags: c#, class, struct, implicit-conversion

Struct/class in question:

```
public struct HttpMethod
{
    public static readonly HttpMethod Get = new HttpMethod("GET");
    public static readonly HttpMethod Post = new HttpMethod("POST");
    public static readonly HttpMethod Put = new HttpMethod("PUT");
    public static readonly HttpMethod Patch = new HttpMethod("PATCH");
    public static readonly HttpMethod Delete = new HttpMethod("DELETE");

    private string _name;

    public HttpMethod(string name)
    {
        // validation of name
        _name = name.ToUpper();
    }

    public static implicit operator string(HttpMethod method)
    {
        return method._name;
    }

    public static implicit operator HttpMethod(string method)
    {
        return new HttpMethod(method);
    }

    public static bool IsValidHttpMethod(string method)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return _name.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _name;
    }
}
```

The following code triggers the issue:

```
public class HttpRoute
{
    public string Prefix { get; }
    public HttpMethod[] Methods { get; }

    public HttpRoute(string pattern, params HttpMethod[] methods)
    {
        if (pattern == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(pattern));
        Prefix = pattern;
        Methods = methods ?? new HttpMethod[0];
    }

    public bool CanAccept(HttpListenerRequest request)
    {
        return Methods.Contains(request.HttpMethod) && request.Url.AbsolutePath.StartsWith(Prefix);
    }
}
```

The compiler error is created by changing the HttpMethod struct into a sealed class. The error is reported for `return Methods.Contains(request.HttpMethod)`, note: `request.HttpMethod` in this case is a `string`. Which produces the following:

```
Error   CS1929  'HttpMethod[]' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.Contains<string>(IQueryable<string>, string)' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable<string>'
```

My question is why? I can redesign the code to make it work, but I'm wanting to know why changing from struct to sealed class creates this weird error.

**Edit**: Adding a simplified set of example code (available here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/IZ9OXg). Take note that commenting *out* the implicit operator to string on the second class allows the code to compile:

```
public static void Main()
{
    HttpMethod1[] Methods1 = new HttpMethod1[10];
    HttpMethod2[] Methods2 = new HttpMethod2[10];

    var res1 = Methods1.Contains("blah"); //works
    var res2 = Methods2.Contains("blah"); //doesn't work
}

public struct HttpMethod1
{
    public static implicit operator HttpMethod1(string method)
    {
        return new HttpMethod1();
    }

    public static implicit operator string (HttpMethod1 method)
    {
        return "";
    }

}

public class HttpMethod2
{
    public static implicit operator HttpMethod2(string method)
    {
        return new HttpMethod2();
    }

    //Comment out this method and it works fine
    public static implicit operator string (HttpMethod2 method)
    {
        return "";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 10):

Things I know:

- Plainly the problem is in type inference.
- In the first case, T is deduced to be HttpMethod1.
- In the struct case, there is no conversion from `HttpMethod1[]` to `IEnumerable<string>` because covariance only works on reference types.
- In the class case, there is no conversion from `HttpMethod2[]` to `IEnumerable<string>` because covariance only works on reference conversions, and this is a user-defined conversion.

Things I suspect but need to confirm:

- Something about the slight difference between my last two points is confusing the type inference algorithm.

UPDATE:

- It has nothing to do with covariant array conversions. The problem repros even without array conversions.
- It *does* however have to do with covariant interface conversions.
- It has nothing to do with strings. (Strings are often a bit weird because they have a hard-to-remember conversion to `IEnumerable<char>` that occasionally messes up type inference.)

Here's a program fragment that displays the problem; update your conversions to convert to C instead of string:

```
public interface IFoo<out T> {}
public class C {}
public class Program
{
    public static bool Contains<T>(IFoo<T> items, T item) 
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(typeof(T));
        return true; 
    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        IFoo<HttpMethod1> m1 = null;
        IFoo<HttpMethod2> m2 = null;
        var res1 = Contains(m1, new C()); //works
        var res2 = Contains(m2, new C()); //doesn't work
    }
    }
```

This looks like a possible bug in type inference, and if it is, it is my fault; many apologies if that is the case. Sadly I do not have time to look into it further today. You might want to open an issue on github and have someone who still does this for a living look into it. I would be fascinated to learn what the result was, and if it turns out to be a bug in either the design or the implementation of the inference algorithm.

Comment: I was soooo hoping that the bounty would attract you to answer this! Thanks!

Comment: The issue doesn't seem to be present in Roslyn v2 (release candidate), I suspect it's not worth filing an issue for this? Or would MS be likely to back port?

Comment: @DavidG: If it doesn't repro in a recent release candidate then it is almost certainly a bug that has been fixed. I cannot speak for Microsoft, but when *I* was fixing those sorts of bugs, I would have argued that it was not worth back-porting the fix. There's an easy workaround, which is to simply supply the type.

Comment: So to clarify, it should work in both cases or it should _not_ work in both cases? Asking because VS thinks that both cases should not work (highlights with red),  though one compiles and other does not.

Comment: @Evk You need to also change the implicit operators to use `C` instead of `string`.

Comment: @DavidG no I mean in original question (with your code provided in a fiddle). VS highlights both cases in red (though one compiles and other does not, as question describes). But I see now you mention that it is fixed in next release, so I guess answer to my question is "it should work in both cases".

Comment: @Evk Are you running Resharper by any chance? Disable it and you should see only the second one is highlighted.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, this is an observed behavioural difference between structs and classes. The fact that you have 'sealed' your class does not affect the outcome in this scenario.

Also we know the following statement will compile as expected for HttpMethod type declared as both a struct and class, thanks to the implicit operator.

```
string method = HttpMethods[0];
```

Dealing with Arrays introduces some lesser understood compiler nuances.

## Covariance

When HttpMethod is a class (reference type), with an array such as HttpRoute.HttpMethods *Array covariance* (12.5 [C# 5.0 Language Spec](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=7029)) comes into play that allows HttpMethod[x] to be treated **as an object**. Covariance will respect inbuilt implicit reference conversions (such as type inheritance or conversion to object) and it will respect explicit operators, but it will not respect or look for user defined implicit operators. *(While a bit ambigous the actual spec doc lists specifically default implicit operators and explicit operators, it does not mention the user defined operators but seeing everything else is so highly specified you can infer that user defined operators are not supported.)*

Basically Covariance takes precedence over many generic type evaluations. More on this in a moment.

> Array covariance specifically does not extend to arrays of value-types. For example, no conversion exists that permits an int[] to be treated as an object[].

So when HttpMethod is a struct (value type), covariance is no longer an issue and the following generic extension from System.Linq namespace will apply:

```
public static bool Contains<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, TSource value);
```

Because you have passed in a string comparator, the Contains statement will be evaluated as follows:

```
public static bool Contains<string>(this IEnumerable<string> source, string value);
```

When HttpMethod is a class (Reference Type), thanks to *covariance*, HttpMethod[] in it's current form comparable only with Object[] and thus IEnumerable, but not IEnumerable< T >, Why not? because the compiler needs to be able to determine the type to generate the generic implementation of IEnumerable< T > and to determine if it can perform an explicit cast from object to T.
Put another way, Compiler cannot determine if T can definetly be a String or not, so it doesn't find the match in the Linq extension methods that we were expecting.

So what can you do about it? **(! Not this !)**
The first common attempt might be to try using .Cast< string >() to cast the HttpMethod instances to strings for the comparison:

```
return HttpMethods.Cast<string>().Contains(request.Method) && request.Url.AbsolutePath.StartsWith(Prefix);
```

You will find that this does not work. Even though The parameter for Cast< T > is of type IEnumerable, not IEnumerable< T >.  It is provided to allow you to use older collections that do not implement the generic version of IEnumerable with LINQ. Cast< T > is only designed to convert non-generic objects to their "true" type through the process of evaluating common origins for reference types or Un-Boxing for value types. If [Boxing and Unboxing (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing) only applies to value types (structs) and since our HttpMethod type is a reference type (class) the only common origin between HttpMethod and String is Object. On HttpMethod there is no implicit, or even explicit operator that accepts Object and as it is not a value type there is no in built un-box operator that the compiler can use.

> Note that this Cast<> will fail at runtime in this scenario when HttpMethod is a value type (class) the compiler will be happy to let it build.

## Final Workaround

Instead of Cast< T > or relying on implicit conversions we will need to force the elements in the HttpMethods array to be *explicitly* cast to string (This will still use out *implicit* operator!) but Linq again makes this a trivial, but necessary task:

```
return HttpMethods.Select(c => (string)c).Contains(request.Method) && request.Url.AbsolutePath.StartsWith(Prefix);
```

Comment: If you see the answer by Eric, it has nothing to do with covariant array conversions.

Comment: Actually Eric backs up my claim, when HttpMethod is a reference type the compiler relies on Covariance to try to get from array of type HttpMethod to enumerable string. But it can't get there because covariance doesn't recognize user defined implicit operators. So yes I agree that it could be listed as a bug in the compiler itself because the type comparison logic should at least consider user defined operators. But recognize that to support such a lookup would add additional overhead to the compiler, so I can see why they didn't support it.

Comment: But look at his example code, there are no arrays there.

Comment: Also you are saying the conversion is from array of type HttpMethod to enumerable string, but it's actually the other way round.

Comment: In Eric's example he has identified another instance where this is also an issue. And yes he has expressed this as Interface Covariance, which is the same mechanism under the hood, except that with Arrays there is an extra check to ensure that all items in the array can be resolved to the same derived type. This reference lists IEnumerable<T> as supporting Covariant type specifiers https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx But again there is no concrete spec that says user defined implicit operators could or should be considered.

Comment: It's worth noting that Eric was a principal dev on the C# compiler team, and worked on this actual thing while he was there, so his opinion is likely correct that it's a bug.

Comment: I totally agree it's an oversight, but we have observed and known about this for a while and have learnt to deal with it. I hadn't considered the attempted conversion from IEnumerable<String> to IEnumerable<HttpMethod> but it all still holds true. Test this by commenting out one of the implicit operators, to force the conversion to go one way or the other, you will get the same result. Which makes sense, it doesn't matter which direction the conversion goes in as it is supposed to be loss less.

Comment: So compared to Eric I'm pretty new but thought I'd give it a crack to explain because I too have studied this a bit after many frustrations as a lowly developer and this discussion is a lot more technical than the general office banter we get day to day so it has been a pretty refreshing :)

Comment: As Eric mentioned, it's a type inference bug, hence the workaround is to explicitly specify the generic type (e.g. `Methods2.Contains<HttpMethod2>("blah")`). No `Cast` method or explicit casts are needed.

Comment: The insight might still be useful I suppose, I'm struggling to understand it fully if I'm being honest. Either way, I guess this is worth a vote :)

Comment: Thank you good sir! My issue was the other way around, I feel like I understand it but not sure how to express it clearly enough, which in part probably makes it harder to understand ;) The c# spec is an interesting gem though that few devs actually bother to read these days. I learnt a few things along the way myself with this one

Comment: I think 95% of devs don't even realise that the C# spec document is on their machine when Visual Studio is installed...